# How to Run this code every 1hr in my server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I want to run "service php7.0-fpm restart && service nginx restart" every 1hr.

Digital Ocean droplet --> nginx, ubuntu

Comment: add a line in /etc/crontab

Answer (score 1):

You can create a cron job for it:
Open it with: `crontab -e` on the terminal

Add a line like this:
`1 2 3 4 5 /command arg1 arg2`
where:

1. Minute (0-59)
2. Hours (0-23)
3. Day (0-31)
4. Month (0-12 [12 == December])
5. Day of the week(0-7 [7 and 0 is sunday])
   /command – This is your command

So you can add:

```
0 * * * *  service php7.0-fpm restart && service nginx restart
```

or instead of the first five fields, you can use one of eight special strings for it and it will look cleaner:

```
@hourly service php7.0-fpm restart && service nginx restart
```

Comment: I added "0 * * * *  service php7.0-fpm restart && service nginx restart" into "crontab -e". Now how to check whether it work?

Comment: You can create a check file that saves the datetime at the end of the command so you can check it was executed. For example: `"0 * * * * service php7.0-fpm restart && service nginx restart && date > $HOME/test.txt"`.